Spring Boot health liveness / readiness probes using all health components by default
I have created a very simple Spring / Boot sample application to test how the liveness and readiness probes work. I configured both Spring Boot 2.7.18 and 3.2.5 In my application properties, I have
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true

When I look at /actuator/health, /actuator/health/liveness or /actuator/health/readiness, then I see all the same components - livenessState, readinessState, diskSpace, ping, and the custom health indicators I created. I didn't expect this, I expected to only see the livenessState or readinessState in the groups, given the Spring docs state "By default, Spring Boot does not add other Health Indicators to these groups". If I set the group members using the "include" property, I see only the indicators listed in the property, which is what I expected. Is this the correct default behavior when the "include" property is not set? If so, is that in the documentation?
